# In which elementary real analysis book are the following proved?

Tags: real-analysis, reference-request, metric-spaces

I am looking for a book where these elementary properties are proved.

- If $X$ is a separable metric space than the Borel sigma-algebra is the same as the sigma-algebra generated by the open balls.
- If X is a separable metric space then $\mathcal{B}(X)\otimes\mathcal{B}(X)=\mathcal{B}(X\times X)$, for an appropriate metric on the product space.

Do you know any books where these results are stated?

Comment: "_A course in real analysis_" by John McDonald and Neil Weiss should contain it (but I read it two years ago so I'm not 100% sure).

Comment: The first proposition follows from (i) a separable metric space is second-countable, and (ii) the general result that if $B$ is a base for a second-countable space  then some countable $B'\subset B$ is a base.  So I expect that a book that explicitly proves the first proposition would likely be a book that states that it does not require, or expect,  much background in general topology .